# Custom DatePicker-iOS

Tags: ios, datepicker

I am getting my JSON data from the server, server get data from the sensor placed in different places collecting info between 6 am-10 pm. I implemented datepicker to be chosen any spefici time wanted to be seen by user. However I would like to exclude 10pm-6am? I want to design my datepicker in a way user could not able choose any time between 10pm-6am. Is there any way to achieve this goal?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use a `UIPickerView`, by making 4 segments as date picker and populate them through arrays

since `UIDatePicker` does not inherit from `UIPickerView` ([which it says in the last sentence of the "Overview" in the Apple documentation which I linked for you](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDatePicker_Class/Reference/UIDatePicker.html)).

`UIPickerView` is what uses a data source.

`UIDatePicker` has a built-in data source which **developers can't touch**.

So, just dump the customised data to the 4 segmented normal picker view.